# How to set environment variable on ubuntu for nodejs pr app

Tags: node.js, azure

Is it possible to set environment variables per nodejs app?

> The azure module will read the environment variables
>   AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE and AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ACCESS_KEY for
>   information required to connect to your Windows Azure Service Bus. If
>   these environment variables are not set, you must specify the account
>   information when calling createServiceBusService.

I would like to set different namespaces/key on a per app lvl instead of global?

(i am hosting it in a ubuntu vm)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for but its possible to set environment variables inside the nodejs application by doing `process.env.AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE = 'something'`

Comment: Can i set them from outside the app? ( I dont want the key to be in my code as its public code on github, so would be nice if I could set them on the system, export Key=Value or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that is possible. But there is something you can do.

In your application just set those environment variables based on others:

```
process.env.AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE = process.env.<APP>_AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE
process.env.AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ACCESS_KEY = process.env.<APP>_AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ACCESS_KEY
```

Its a little more verbose but I am not sure if you can set dynamic environment variables.

Comment: Thats a decent solution :) I will use that for now.

Comment: is the <APP> something i should change, then its kinda the same problem that i cant reuse the module without changing it.

Comment: Ya there are ways to make it dynamic.
You could always pass in the App name on initialization and access it like so `process.env.AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE = process.env[appName.toUpperCase()+'_AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE']`

Comment: Thanks this is what i did first, then i realized that when i do set key=value in the command window, then its only local for that command window. So i can just start my node apps from different commandwindows and its no problem. thanks.